# Xtext Cross-Referencing: Following function parameter names

Tags: xtext

I am struggling to cross-reference via the name of a function parameter in a function definition, *and* battling to Google the solution. Consider following example.

```
def helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World!"
} 

def combine(Person person, Place place) {
    return person.name + place.code  // ❎ Couldn't resolve reference to Feature 'name'. 
}          


entity Person {
    name: String
    title : String
    occupation : String
}

entity Place  {
    name: String
    code:String
}

datatype String
```

The grammar is the following, which extends the standard example with a *very* simple notion of function *definition* via a simple expression language.

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Domainmodel :
    (
        elements+=Type |
        functions+=Function // Note Functions
    )*;

/********************  Functions ********************/

Function : 'def' name=ID '('
    (parameters+=Parameter (',' parameters+=Parameter)*)? 
    ')' '{' 'return' exp=Exp    '}'
;

Parameter: type=[Entity] name=ID;   

Exp:
   TerminalExp 
   ({Exp.left=current} 
     '+' 
     right=TerminalExp)*;

TerminalExp : value=STRING | dotExpression = DotExpression;

/******************** PROBLEM AREA ********************/

DotExpression : parameterRef=[Parameter] '.' featureRef=FeatureRef;

FeatureRef  :   featureRef=[Feature];

/********************  THE USUAL ********************/

Type:
    DataType | Entity;

DataType:
    'datatype' name=ID;

Entity:
    'entity' name=ID  '{'
        (features+=Feature)*
    '}';

Feature:
     name=ID ':' type=[Type];
```

This grammar parses perfectly, but the dotted use of a function parameter name is not linking properly. My scope provider is the following, the latter exception throwing method concerns a secondary issue.

```
/*
 * generated by Xtext 2.14.0
 */
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.scoping

import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EReference
import org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.IScope
import org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.Scopes
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.DotExpression
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.FeatureRef

class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractMyDslScopeProvider  {

    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        if (context instanceof FeatureRef) {
            val myDotExpression = (context as EObject/*?*/).eContainer as DotExpression 
            val features = myDotExpression.parameterRef.type.features
            println("### " + features.stream.map["[" + name + "]"].reduce("", [$0 + $1]))
            Scopes::scopeFor(features)
        }
        super.getScope(context, reference)
    }

    def IScope scope_FeatureRef(FeatureRef context, EReference ref) {
        println("### I have been called")
        throw new RuntimeException("I HAVE BEEN CALLED!");
    }

}
```

The following output demonstrates that (1) the correct objects are found and that they have then expected names, and (2) that the latter method is never called.

```
### [name][title][occupation]
### [name][code]
### [name][title][occupation]
### [name][code]
```

1. What mistake am I making in in the first scope method?
2. Why is the latter method never called?

*I have read [Xtext and Dot/Path-Expressions](https://www.dietrich-it.de/xtext/2013/05/18/xtext-and-dot-expressions.html) and [Runtime Concepts:Scoping](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#scoping). I have also seen the solution before, but have tried unsuccessfully for days to Google it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scope_` methods are only valid if you inherit from `AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider`
and it should be named `scope_FeatureRef_featureRef`

and dont forget to return

`return Scopes::scopeFor(features)`

the important part is the **return**

Comment: So, what would you propose to solve the problem? Let the class inherit or change other parts?

Comment: You can do both. I’d propose to replace the scope_with if else in the getScope

Comment: But is that not what I am doing in the first method? The second scope_ method is not being called. The pure getScope method is being called, but do not understand why it is not working. It is returning what seems to be the correct proposals, and these proposals seem to have the correct name, from the output. What is wrong the the getScope method?

Comment: I have changed to a AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider. The output is exactly as before: the scope_ method is not called, and the getScope method is called, and prints the same output as above.

Comment: The name is bogus should be scope_FeatureRef_feature

Comment: I have updated the OP to make it clear that I have two questions, (1) why my getScope method is not corect, and (2) why the scope_ method is not being called.

Comment: Making that correction seems to make not difference with regard to (2). Here is the new code with an extra # to prove really building. Only the getScope method is called. class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider  { ...
 def IScope scope_FeatureRef_feature(FeatureRef context, EReference ref) {
  println("#### I have been called")
  throw new RuntimeException("I HAVE BEEN CALLED!");
 }
}

Comment: Thank you so much. Change "Scopes::scopeFor(features)" to "return Scopes::scopeFor(features)" and "super.getScope(context, reference)" to "return super.getScope(context, reference)" and all is working perfectly. I have obviously misunderstood the Xtend semantics. Perhaps emphasise in your answer that my mistake was to omit the return statement. I know it is there, but perhaps just embolden the return. Once again, thank you.